# ImportError: No module named _grabscreen

Tags: python

I am new to python and using this tutorial http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-build-a-python-bot-that-can-play-web-games--active-11117 to build a bot which plays games.

I copy-pasted the file and installed the libraries .When i tried running the file in the terminal on my mac i got this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 2, in <module>
    import Image, ImageGrab, ImageOps
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageGrab.py", line 34, in <module>
    import _grabscreen
ImportError: No module named _grabscreen
```

Here is the complete code

```
import os, sys
import Image, ImageGrab, ImageOps
import time, random
from random import randrange
import win32api, win32con
from numpy import *
```

Comment: Your code fails on the second line - all of the rest of it is completely irrelevant!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should pay attention to the these words in the tutorial, 'Some of the code and libraries are Windows-specific. There may be Mac or Linux equivalents, but we won't be covering them in this tutorial.'.

And current version of ImageGrag only works for windows.